# GMaps - placing more than 100 markers

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using `gmaps` in my website and want to place more then hundred of markers in `google maps` to show users location. Can it break down the connection or slow down the speed of my website when accessing all of these marker through `json` data. As these markers data stored in `array` file.

```
var values = [
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.120850", "name" : "a new user" },
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.420850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.520850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.620850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.720850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.820850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-0.920850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-1.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-2.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"},
  {"lat" : "51.508742", "ln" : "-3.320850" , "name" : "my corporation"}
]
```

And I am accessing them as:

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(values[0]["lat"],values[0]['ln']);



function initialize()
{
  var marker;
  function callMe(v,i){
    marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(values[i]["lat"],values[i]['ln']) ,
    });
    marker.setMap(map);
  }
  var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  values.forEach(callMe);


}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

**Can I show all of these markers concurrently or should I limit them for performance?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should limit the number of markers.  But this isn't a limitation on `JSON`.  It's a factor of web performance and visual overload.

[From Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers):

> Some applications are required to display a large number of locations
>   or markers. Naively plotting thousands of markers on a map can quickly
>   lead to a degraded user experience. Too many markers on the map cause
>   both visual overload and sluggish interaction with the map. To
>   overcome this poor performance, the information displayed on the map
>   needs to be simplified.

Google suggests the following methods to assist with limiting the number of markers displayed at one time:

1. [Grid-based Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#gridbasedclustering)
2. [Distance-based Clustering](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#distancebasedclustering)
3. [Viewport Marker Management](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#viewportmarkermanagement)
4. [Fusion Tables](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#fusiontables)
5. [MarkerClusterer](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markerclusterer)
6. [MarkerManager](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/toomanymarkers#markermanager)